# Not able to use selectors in JMS selector with ActiveMQ & Spring Boot java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.filter.JAXPXPathEvaluator

Tags: spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a JMS listener having selectors and after migration to Spring Boot 3.1.0 I am facing issues when I provide values to selectors in my config file.

Below is the listener which I am using:

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "${queue.demo.task.destination}",
        selector = "${queue.demo.task.selector}")
public void handle(@Payload String taskconfirmation, Message jmsMessage) throws JMSException {
    ActiveMQTextMessage activeMQTextMessage = (ActiveMQTextMessage)jmsMessage;
    LOGGER.debug(ListenerUtility.getLoginfo(activeMQTextMessage));
    messageService.createTaskDemo(taskConfirmation, jmsMessage.getJMSDestination().toString(),XYZ)
                                     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).subscribe();
}
```

Below is the config :

queue:
demo:
task:   destination:${default.queue.demo.task.destination:${namespace:default}.ABC}
selector: "XPATH '//msg/Header/messageType="123"'"

Below is the error message :

```
2023-06-27 12:25:52,692 ERROR [o.a.activemq.filter.XPathExpression     ,Container#13-14]  (,,,,,) : Default XPath evaluator could not be loaded 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.filter.JAXPXPathEvaluator
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:133)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
```

Comment: Which and what version of ActiveMQ "Classic" dependencies are you using in your project?

Comment: Hi @JustinBertram,
Indeed the reason is that.. Do u have any good reference to use selectors using the activemq-broker.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that `org.apache.activemq.filter.JAXPXPathEvaluator` is coming from the `activemq-broker` module which doesn't yet have a Jakarta implementation. The issue isn't with selectors in general. It's only with *XPath* selectors. It looks like you'll have to wait for ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.19.0 to be released as that will have a Jakarta version of the `activemq-broker` module.

Aside from that you could move to [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) (i.e. the next generation broker from ActiveMQ) which has shipped both a client and broker Jakarta EE implementation for the last few years. It also supports [XPath selectors](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/filter-expressions.html#xpath), and it is [directly supported in Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.jms.artemis).